# Mongoose findByIdAndRemove returns null

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to delete a note using mongoose findByIdAndRemove here:

```
app.post("/delete", async (req, res) => {
const userId = req.session.userId;
const foundUser = await User.findById(userId).exec();
console.log(foundUser);
if (foundUser) {
    const itemId = req.body.itemId.toString();
    const foundNote = await Note.findByIdAndRemove(itemId).exec();
    console.log(foundNote);
    if (foundNote) {
        res.redirect("/main")
}
}


});
```

This is what my user object looks like

```
{
_id: new ObjectId("6537d3aa0bf4dd1fb949f084"),
username: 'test9@email.com',
notes: [
{
  noteBody: 'test9a',
  userId: '6537d3aa0bf4dd1fb949f084',
  _id: new ObjectId("6537d3ba0bf4dd1fb949f08a")
}
],
__v: 1
}
```

When I try to delete a note the console.log(foundNote) returns null.
I think I am "finding" in the wrong place but I am not sure how to find what I want. Which is user.notes._id. and then delete that particular note.

Here is a link to the whole code at github https://github.com/ETurner-Bisset/Not-It

Thanks in advance.

edit:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
email: String,
password: String,
notes: [noteSchema]
});

const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

noteBody: String,
userId: String
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your `User` schema shows that your `notes` field is an array of [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#subdocuments). That means they don't have their own collection and you can't issue a `find*` query using the `Note` model. They are embedded in each `User` document in your `users` collection as opposed to being [referenced](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs).

> Subdocument data is embedded in the top-level document. Referenced documents are separate top-level documents.

This means you have to `$pull` or `pull()` the item from the `notes` array of the `User` document. Thankfully, this can be done in one query. You can use `findByIdAndUpdate` or `findOneAndUpdate` but since you are passing the `userId` then you can use `findByIdAndUpdate` like so:

```js
const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId,
   { 
      $pull: {
         notes: { _id: req.body.itemId }
      }
   },
   {new:true} //< This option returns the document after update has taken place
);
```

As an aside, this isn't needed:

```
const itemId = req.body.itemId.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked and it was very easy to understand. I had been having trouble wrapping my head around some of the structure involved.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your project.